# Issue generating program output to .txt file

Tags: c, output

I am currently enrolled in college and taking a programming course. The program seems to function correctly, however in order to submit my lab I need to provide the output via .txt file. When I go to find the file, it comes up blank. I am very new to coding and would appreciate any help in the simplest form of understanding. I have attached my program below. I am referencing my books "Focus on Fundamentals of Programming with C" and "Problem Solving and Program Design in C"

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 

#include<stdio.h>
#define SECS_PER_HOUR 3600 //1 hour = 60 minutes in an hour * 60 seconds in a minute = 
3600 seconds in 1 hour
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1600

FILE *fp;

int main()
{
    double distance, time, speed_mph, speed_mps;

    fopen_s(&fp, "csis.txt", "w");

    scanf("%lf", &distance);
    scanf("%lf", &time);

    speed_mph = distance / time;
    speed_mps = (speed_mph * METERS_PER_MILE) / SECS_PER_HOUR;

    printf("\nThe speed is %.2f miles per hour. \n", speed_mph);
    printf(fp, "\nThe speed is %.2f miles per hour. \n", speed_mph);

    printf("The speed is %.2f meters per second.", speed_mps);
    printf(fp, "The speed is %.2f meters per second.", speed_mps);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler warnings are your best friend and advisor: "incompatible types - from 'FILE *' to 'const char *const '". Your `printf(fp, ...` needs to be `fprintf(fp, ...`

Comment: You are not checking that `fopen( )` succeeded... ALWAYS check return codes! Aside: `#define SECS_PER_HOUR 3600` could be `#define SECS_PER_HOUR 60*60` requiring less explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Use fprintf to write to the file.

```
printf("\nThe speed is %.2f miles per hour. \n", speed_mph);
fprintf(fp, "\nThe speed is %.2f miles per hour. \n", speed_mph);

printf("The speed is %.2f meters per second.", speed_mps);
fprintf(fp, "The speed is %.2f meters per second.", speed_mps);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the response. Defiantly oversaw that one. Learning has occured